# Appending a values of a list to a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list `list1 = [1, 2, 3]` and I would like to append it to another list, such that I get `list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3]]`. I would like then to append more and get something like `list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`.

My problem is that I am doing this in a loop and I am using the same list to be appended many times with different values, however when I clear the list with `list1.clear()`, then also the values I appended are cleared. Here the full code

```
list_of_lists = []
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

list_of_lists.append(list1)
list1.clear()

print(list_of_lists)
```

the output is [[]]. How should I fix this? Thanks

Comment: can you share the loop ? the exact full code so we can reproduce ,

Comment: Can you show the way you are using a loop in your example?

Comment: Thank you all. From the comments I now got my mistake, it was using append(list) instead of append(list[:]). Then clearing the list I was clearing the appended one as well.

Comment: it looks like a memory reference issue because you are adding the object list1 and after you are cleaning the same object, this clean the unique object in memory and update both vars

Comment: `list[:]` is useless, better NOT clearing the list, but reassigning an empty one `list1 = []`

Comment: I can't do that because this is done in while a loop.

Comment: could you share the loop code ? if you do clear, you can also reassign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine, the only thing you would need to change is when you add list1 to list_of_lists add it as such:

```
list_of_lists.append(list(list1))
```

Everything should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
listOfLists = []
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

listOfLists.append(list1)
print(listOfLists)
listOfLists.append(list2)
print(listOfLists)
```

or something like this?

```
listOfLists = []
list1 = [1,2,3]
listOfLists.append(list1)
print(listOfLists)
list1 = []
# append numbers to list1 in loop

    list1.append(x)

listOfLists.append(list1)
print(listOfLists)
```